# What determines load order for multiple UITableViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with 3 different UITableViews on it.  Two of the tables depend on what is in the third.  When the app starts, it's loading the two dependent tables before it loads the independent one, so I am not getting the behavior expected.  If I continue to a different screen then come back, I get the expected behavior, so I know my code that dictates the behavior is correct.  What I think I need to do is specify which table is processed by `cellForRowAtIndexPath` first.  Can that be done in `viewDidLoad`, or anywhere else for that matter?  How does it determine which table to process first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On loading, you don't know the order. You could guess but it might be different in different iOS versions so it's not worth the effort.

To fix it, in your `viewDidLoad` method, just call `reloadData` for the table views in the order you need :)

However, the fact that you have a load order for the table views means that you proably haven't separated out your data and your UI enough :) You're table views shouldn't depend on each other, they should depend on variables that are stored in your view controller so they can be reloaded in any order at any point (in an ideal world :)

Comment: Wow, `reloadData` was the simple fix I needed.  I though of that, but I didn't think it would work, because when I stepped through the code, it was calling `viewDidLoad` before the first call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so I thought I would get the same result, but actually trying it proved that it works (and that I'm not starting to understand this as much as I thought I am =( ).

Comment: As far as the dependent tables on the same view thing goes, it's pretty much a customer requirement that the tables need to be viewed together, so I guess it's my job to find a way to make it work, instead of telling the customer how they are supposed to want it =).

Comment: gah, disregard last.  Turns out I made my code that determines the behavior in a stupid way - case of "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail".  I thought about it for a minute, and I was able to clean it up so it was based on a var on the view controller after all.  Thanks!